# Can't add, nor update service reference in asp.net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently changed one method in the web service(deleted 1 input argument, so now there are 3), cleaned the solution, built the solution several times, but the error "no overload takes 3 arguments" kept appearing.

I tried to delete and add the reference again, and this error appeared: http://pastebin.com/QTzG235S.

I made new web service, copy-pasted the code from the old one, but still no results, same error appears.

When I try to access it in browser this appears:

> Runtime Error Description: An exception occurred while processing your
>   request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the
>   custom error page for the first exception. The request has been
>   terminated.

What the heck happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, the name of the following class somehow changed:

From:

```
public class DbVideos : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

To:

```
public class DbVideosXml
```

Resulting in this error.

I just renamed it as the service name and it worked again.

`Edit`: On next change in methods, booom, same problem again. 
Copy-paste methods in new web service, restart vs, clean solution, and somehow it fixed itself on 100-th try. Therefore, aliens...